# Use Shibboleth as SP, Azure AD as IDP

Tags: azure

I have several application already running on SAML2 with Azure AD as IDP. I have an on premise webapp with Shibboleth as SP (currently talking to another IDP). I want to change this so Shibboleth goes to Azure AD for authentication.

I have created an additional ApplicationOverride and provided the metadata and attribute-extractor files (comparable to the ones used in the current setup with the current IDP).

When accessing the website, I am redirected to Azure, I can authenticate there and then I'm sent back to my website, where Shibboleth tells me:

> shibsp::ConfigurationException
>      The system encountered an error at Mon Jan 14 16:05:48 2019
>      To report this problem, please contact the site administrator at emailaddress .
>      Please include the following message in any email:
>      shibsp::ConfigurationException at (https:///Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST)
>      No MetadataProvider available.

I have tried with Process Explorer (its a windows server) to see if any metadata files are missing or not found, but that's all ok.

Shibd.log does not contain any errors.

Can someone point me in the direction where I should start?

Comment: were you able to get this working?  I'd be interested in seeing your solution to this.